# R: For loop is only executed once

Tags: r, for-loop

Why is the following code only run once?

```
  for ( i in length( which( rowSums( m ) != 1 ) ) ) {
      m[which( rowSums( m ) != 1 )[i], ncol( m )] <- 1
      print(i)
  }
```

m is matrix that contains values between 0 and 1 under the condition that the sum of each row can't exceed 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `1:length( which( rowSums( m ) != 1 ))`

You want to iterate through a vector in your loop.

Comment: It is better to use `seq_len` or `seq_along` functions instead of `1:length(` because what if the length happens to be 0?

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. But there still seems something wrong, because only the last value is changed to 1. All the other values are the same as before.

Comment: @GregSnow, you make a valid point. If the length is zero, it will throw an error for `seq_len` but not for `1:length(` so I suppose it's up to OP.

Comment: @JimBoy, try to print the vector and see what's in it